# OpenOnload driver error "insmod: ERROR: could not insert module........Unknown symbol in module"

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, driver

I'm on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS and wish to install OpenOnload for kernel bypass of NICs.

I followed the instructions here:

https://github.com/Xilinx-CNS/onload/blob/master/DEVELOPING.md

(Ubuntu 20.04 LTS is supported by Onload)

I've built the repo from source and I've just attempted this part:

```
To load drivers into the kernel:

"$(mmaketool --toppath)/build/$(mmaketool --driverbuild)/driver/linux/load.sh" onload
```

Unfortunately I get the error:

```
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module 
onload/build/x86_64_linux-5.15.0-46-generic/driver/linux/sfc_resource.ko: Unknown symbol in module
```

This seems to be a generic error relating to inserting drivers in to the Linux kernel but I'm not sure how to fix it. I had all the dependencies installed. I've ran this on a bare metal machine and a virtual machine and got the same problem both times.

Can anyone help/try it too?

**UPDATE**

I checked `dmesg | tail` and there is this entry:

`init_sfc_resource: ERROR: failed to find syscall table`

But still not sure how to fix it

Comment: **Linux kernel in the range 4.15 - 5.16** from the [README.md](https://github.com/Xilinx-CNS/onload/blob/master/README.md).  The curren t mainline does not contain the `init_sfc_resource` symbol.

Comment: @artlessnoise Hi. But the Github page says it supports Ubuntu 20.04? Does this mean I need to install a custom kernel or is there a distro I could just use?

Comment: I have Ubuntu 22.04 and it is using 5.15.  You may need to compile a custom kernel.  I looked and this is defined in ['linux_resource'](https://github.com/Xilinx-CNS/onload/blob/master/src/driver/linux_resource/resource_driver.c#L773), so I think it is a symptom as opposed to the primary cause.

Answer (score -1):

Ran into the same issue 20.04 LTS with 5.13 still works , but 5.15 is not.

Comment: This does not provide an answer and should be a comment. I know you probably can't comment for now, before you get enough reputation; but in the meantime, you should not use answer as comment.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33526568)